# Append text to the beginning of every line in a file

Tags: java

Please note, this is a homework assignment.

Can anybody help me figure out how to append text to the beginning of every line of a text file?  This is what I have so far:

```
package addStr;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class AddStr {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        Scanner con = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter input file: ");
            String fileIn = con.next();
        System.out.print("Enter output file: ");
            String fileOut = con.next();

        File in = new File(fileIn);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(in);
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter(in, true);
        PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(out);


        print.print("hello");


        print.close();
    }

}
```

I only printed "hello" as a test to see where in the file it would append.  It appends at the end of the very last line.  I need it to append to the beginning of the first line, and then use a loop to append it to the beginning of each subsequent line.

Also, the program prompts the user to input the file name.

Comment: So your output will be newText + restOfFile?

Comment: I need to append the text to the beginning of each line in the file.

Comment: You cannot read from and write to the same file simultaneously.  The only way to do this is to write to a temporary file, then when you are done rename the old file, rename the new file, delete the old file.  Or read from stdin and write to stdout and let the user specify redirection on the command line.

Comment: How about adding the text first, then the contents of the text file after that text has been printed so for example the text you want to append in front is ADMIN, you could print ADMIN then the contents of the file

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to change the content of a file is to open it for reading, read it into a structure, re-open the file for writing then write from the structure back to file. Unless the file is large then the performance will be perfectly acceptable.

If you are using Java 8 then this can be quite trivial. Assuming you have a `Path` to the file:

```
List<String> lines = Files.lines(path).map(s -> "Prefix" + s).collect(Collectors.toList());
Files.write(path, lines);
```